# How do I allow an external user to add bug/work items

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

We are using TFS 2010 in my company but are only using its VSS feature.
For adding/updating any bug/feature request, we are using Assembla... mainly because of the reason that we also want to allow external users to add/update a work item.

I Googled and found that TFS supports a feature called 'Work Item Only View(WIOV)'.

Can you please guide me what OTHER options are available so that all internal/expernal bug/work item save only in TFS database.

Also, anyone using WIOV can please suggest how well it can help me in above scenerio.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that [this blog](http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2010/07/14/quick-and-easy-setup-for-ldquowork-item-only-viewrdquo-web-users-in-tfs-2010) describes what you're trying to do

Comment: Thanks for yor reply James, but my query was not regarding 'How To..', I am looking for any other option than WIOV if available.

Comment: Sorry about that, I think that there may be other options i.e. allow your customers to access the full Web UI of TFS, or write an application that connects directly to the TFS web services. However, anything other than using WIOV would probably require the users to have a TFS Client Access Licence, either individualy or by organisation.